# UIImageView image not seen while set from Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, storyboard, uiimageasset

In a story board view, I am adding an image view as a subview. Then I set image for that image view. But, I cannot see the image for that image view. What I am seeing is just an question mark. Here is how it looks:

[image]

---

You can see that I have set an **ChaptersBg** as an image. I have added that in **Assets.xcassets**. My App is only for iPad, so chosen *iPad* in *Devices*. Here is how I have added that image:

---

[image]

I can see both the **1x** and **2x** images in the preview, but not in image view. Image view is of size **420 X 100**. Thus 1x has resolution **420 X 100** and 2x has resolution **840 X 200**.

Everything seems ok but I cannot see the image there. I also tried it by setting programmatically but no impact at all..

What may be the reason ???

> EDIT 1:

When I **(1)** Remove constraints of image view **(2)** Set image programmatically —— then and then I can see image at runtime.

Comment: Try using some extension to images like .jpeg or .png

Comment: Tried JPG and PNG both..

Comment: Did u try removing them and adding them again

Comment: Yes I have tried from scratch, i.e. removing image asset for that images and adding again..

Comment: when you start typing the image name, it comes in the suggestions right??

Comment: Yes comes in list and I choose it from there only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it should work from what I see. Xcode gets weird sometimes when it comes to referencing resources. I recommend removing the images, clean and build and add again. See if it works.